# Getting started with Twilio SMS and raspberry pi

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, raspberry-pi, twilio

This is more of a systems level question but I'm having some issues getting started with the Twilio java libraries, and Apache Tomcat 7 on the raspberry pi 2. My end goal is to have Twilio pass on sms messages to the raspberry pi for control some simple switches. (Overkill for now, but with the connectivity options the pi offers I want to eventually implement some rich control/ interactivity in the system)

I am trying to implement the simple example code from twilio:

```
package com.twilio;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.twilio.sdk.verbs.TwiMLResponse;
import com.twilio.sdk.verbs.TwiMLException;
import com.twilio.sdk.verbs.Message;

public class TwilioServlet extends HttpServlet {

// service() responds to both GET and POST requests.
// You can also use doGet() or doPost()
    public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        TwiMLResponse twiml = new TwiMLResponse();
        Message message = new Message("Hello, Mobile Monkey");
        try {
            twiml.append(message);
        } catch (TwiMLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        response.setContentType("application/xml");
        response.getWriter().print(twiml.toXML());
    }
}
```

I have compiled this using the twilio libraries and put the following web.xml in the WEB-INF directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <display-name>Twilio SMS App</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>TwilioServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.twilio.TwilioServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>TwilioServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/sms</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

However, when I go to load this page in a browser, Tomcat gives me an error:

Apache Tomcat/7.0.28 - Error report

## HTTP Status 404 -

**type** Status report

**message**

**description** The requested resource () is not available.

#### Apache Tomcat/7.0.28

Occasionally if I am lucky, the server will actually give me:

```
The requested resource (twilio/sms)
```

I wrote a different servlet which prints hello world, and that displays fine using the url extension twilio/hello. I think this has something to do with where Tomcat is looking for the Twilio api stuff, but I am not too familiar with web development or java in general so I'm kind of at a loss. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It's Megan from Twilio here.

When you say that you tried a "Hello World" example using the url extension `twilio/hello` I assume you followed the [local dev environment setup here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/devenvironment).

In the following example, the code looks near identical to what you've posted above but have you done the next step titled, [Let Twilio find your server](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/twiml/say-response)?

In addition to the quickstarts I found [these](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/how-to-warm-transfer-a-call-with-java-and-twilio-voice.html) [posts](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/10/create-a-standalone-voicemail-using-java-and-twilio.html) using Java and Apache Tomcat especially helpful when working with Java and Twilio for the first time.

Hope this helps!